# How to bind data in gridview format in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, c#-4.0, gridview

Hi i am developing windows phone 8 app.i want to display image on grid view format and i am using listbox inside grid but i didn't get any changes in my output.my code is given below,I want display data on grid view format.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,115,0,0" Background="#424340" Grid.RowSpan="5" />

    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0.083" Grid.Row="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListBox x:Name="List12" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="NotchsList12_SelectionChanged"
           Margin="0,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="left" Width="Auto"  Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titles}" Foreground="Black" Width="189" Height="34" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="0,0,0,0"></TextBlock>

                        <Image Source="{Binding Images}"  Width="189" Height="195" Name="value"  Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="Text1" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>


XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(dataInXmlFile);

            var query = from l in xmlDoc.Descendants("Category")
                        select new Class
                        {
                            Titles = l.Attribute("title").Value,
                            Images = l.Attribute("image").Value,

                       Articles = l.Element("SubCategory").Elements("Subcategory")
                                         .Select(article => new Subclass
                                         {
                                             name = article.Attribute("name").Value,

                                             Subimage = article.Attribute("subimage").Value,
                                             Product = article.Element("Product").Elements("product")
                                                            .Select(articles => new Product
                                                            {
                                                                Price = articles.Element("productprice").Value,
                                                                ProductName = articles.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                                ProductImage = articles.Element("productimage").Value,
                                                                Shortdescription = articles.Element("productshortdiscription").Value
                                                            }).ToList(),

                                         })
                                         .ToList(),



                        };

            foreach (var result in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.Titles);
                Console.WriteLine(result.Images);

            }

            List12.DataContext = query;
```

**I got out put like given below**

1.Door  2.window  3.table  4.chair

**I need out put like given below image**

1.Door    2.window

3.table   4.chair

Answer (score 0):

make ur `stackPanel` Orientation `Vertical` instead of `Horizontal`

```
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use grid, instead use LongListSelector using LayoutMode=Grid

Example:

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="200,200">
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Border Background="#e67e22" Height="190" Width="190" Margin="6,0,0,0" Tap="Border_Tap" >
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
</Border>
</DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```